# Add a custom text in WooCommerce login page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-registration, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce login page, I need to add a statement **"Not a user? register now"** under the login form next to **"lost your password?"** to let the unregistered user go easily to the registration page when pressing on this statement.

So, how can I add it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_after_customer_login_form`** action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form', 'custom_login_text' );
function custom_login_text() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        //Your link
        $link = home_url( '/register' );

        // The displayed (output)
        echo '<p>'. __("Not a user? <a href='$link'>register now<a/>", "woocommerce").'</p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, found this answer from a while back. It works fine. Do you have an idea on how can i print that paragraph below the H2 login title (and about the form)? thanks!